# How to keep js/jquery at the bottom in (MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am aware its a best practice to put your javascript/jquery at the bottom of the page.

But how exactly can i achieve this "best practice"?

In my current webproject (MVC4) I have placed my javascript at the bottom.
But i am unable to make anything work unless i put my javascript in the header(which is considered bad practice?).

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <!--js function that calls upon jQuery (slider) -->
  </div>
</div>

  <!--Javascript declaration-->
</body>
```

For example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

The function slider.js requires jQuery to make my slider work.

Is there a way to keep all my javascript files (including jQuery) at the bottom and load jQuery (or a other function / library) if a function needs to access it?

***Update***

The problem seems to be with the MVC **bundles**.
When i put the javascript files in the normal syntax at the bottom everything works.

Are separate bundles required? Not sure in what kind of order MVC loads the bundles.

When applying this kind of bundle (jquery first followed by the js function) the order of exection is wrong.

**Because of this i cannot really see the advantage of bundles, someone care to explain?**

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js",                    
                        "~/Scripts/js/slider.js"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? I always have my scripts at the bottom of my page, so yes you should be able to do the same. Do you have any JavaScript executing before the onload?

Comment: Change https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js into //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js without http or https in front of it to make it adapt to the current protocol.

Comment: Adding the JS on the header is not necessarily a bad practice but it's recommended to place them in the bottom of the page to rather let the other DOM elements load first before executing on those elements. The question is, how are you executing the slider.js and other plugins? Are they placed in order of execution? Those are the things that you need to look into.

Comment: Updated OP post with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is good is because browsers load scrips synchronously with the web page.  So if you put them at the top, loading big scrips will stall the content loading.  If you place it at the bottom before the close of the body tag, the content will load first, thus making the page pop up much faster without the stall of scripts.

To fix your problem, wrap all of your executing code in a document.ready, or the jquery equivalent:

```
$(function(){
//your code here
})
```

If jQuery is not loaded yet, you can check with a console.log:

```
if(!window.jQuery)
{
console.log("problem");
}
```

You haven't provided much information here, which makes it hard to debug. All I can do is give you the steps to do it.  You just have to make sure that jQuery is loaded before any other script runs on the page.

Do you have inline script tags in your page?

Comment: Is load not better then document.ready (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? But what do you exactly mean with all my executing code? That still does not load jquery before i call my $function for my slider?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to put those at the bottom as long as the jQuery import is before your script. Do you have other javascript in your page which depends on either of those scripts?